# HTML how to get Scrollbar on a div content with variable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am struggling to get scrollbar in below scenario:

> Parent DIV 1 (Fixed Height 200px) - No scrollbar
>   - Child DIV 1 (Max Height 100px - Content varies from empty to maximum) - Should have scrollbar if needed
>   - Child DIV 2 (Height = Div 1 - Child1 height) - Should have scroll bar if needed

Here's my attempt:

```css
#body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border: black dashed 2px;
}
#head {
  border: green solid 1px;
}
#content {
  border: red solid 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
#content {
  border: red solid 1px;
  overflow-y: in;
  height: 200px;
}
#content1 {
  border: red solid 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}
#content2 {
  border: red solid 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#foot {
  border: blue solid 1px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="head">
    <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content1">
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
      <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="foot">
    <p>Fixed size without scrollbar</p>
    <p>Fixed size without scrollbar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/712Lk1v5/1/)

Comment: Worked for me..whats wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

No height is set to your Content2 div. That is why there is no scroll bar. it should have some specific height set to it.